# Modal ScatterViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, pixelsense, scatterview

Can anyone please point out how could i possibly create a modal ScatterViewItem?
I want a ScatterViewItem that will stay on top preventing interaction with anything else until closed. Kind of like a myWindowInstance.ShowDialog() in window forms.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Make it the only item in a scatterview.  Set the scatterview's background to Transparent (which, unlike a null background, will block input from going through it).